# (How) can I pause a mysql query from executing right as it starts, for a certain amount of time (and be notified of this event live)?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, debugging

I have a series of complex python / bash scripts doing *all sorts of stuff*.

Some of them run mysql queries to create a database and tables.

Say i was too lazy to go through all of them to see when and who creates my tables, and i just wanted to pause the script execution at that point.

I expect 2 things at this point:

- To know that mysql stopped because a table is being created (or whatever else)
- To see in my console that my installation scripts stopped - and spot the script currently running.

So is there a way to pause such types of queries?

Comment: The MySQL client will wait on the server to complete execution of each command before transmitting the next.  It is straightforward to suspend a Bash script immediately - just send it the suspend character (^Z in most terminals): see [Job Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control) for more information.  However, if you are seeking to pause execution of the session at the MySQL server, then I don't think that it's possible: the closest thing would be to [`KILL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/kill.html) the connection or query and manually resume.

Comment: currently workig on a trigger that does it with the help of the `SLEEP(X);` function. will update.